# INDEX MATCH formula instead showing result show zeros

Tags: excel

I saw some [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fYlWeMQ6L8) to make the unique list of names dynamically in Excel. but when I applied this formula to my data I got zero instead of the result value. I tested this formula on sample data but Still get zeros.

the formula is :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[names],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$5:$E$13,Table2[names]),),0)),””)
```

the sample table is 
[image]

when I press the F9 button on the formula box I see the correct result
[image]

also, I changed the formula to this one but there is no change in the result.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[names],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$4:$E5,Table2[names]),),0)),””)
```

the difference is in the $E$4:$E5

**UPDATE**:

thanks to @Rory for answering. the problem was in a circular reference.

to solve that the problem the formula must be like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[names],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$4:$E4,Table2[names]),),0)),””)
```

Comment: The answer is correct after pressing the `ctrl+shift+enter` now you just need to drag it down. You will have unique values

Comment: thanks, but I made mistake in my question. I meant F9, not ctrl+shift+enter. I edit question. @Hafiz

Comment: You're creating a circular reference.

Comment: @Rory, How I can fix the problem? I just copy the formula base on the tutorial.

Comment: I change the formula to this. but the result is the same.
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[names],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$4:$E5,Table2[names]),),0)),””)

Comment: If that's in E5 the second cell in the countif needs to also be E4: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[names],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$4:$E4,Table2[names]),),0)),””)`